# Filter number out of string

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string, file

I would like to know if I can filter out the frame padding at the end of this string.

`new_york.0001.tga`

There's 1000's of images, all have a similar pattern:

`filename.padding.extension`

Basically, I want to find the padding in any file name I pass my functions, example:

`new_york.0001.tga` Should find `0001`

`s._2234.name.8923482.jpg` Should find `8923482`

`s.sdf&#$.s.d__.name.s23444.tiff` Should find `23444`

All image names padding number, will be directly before the extension, that's the only thing that's continuous in the filename.

I suck at regex and would love to learn how to do it, some guidance may be in order though...

Thankyou!

Comment: Do you prefer JS or PHP?

Comment: Is there any chance you could show what you have tried? Where were you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple [**.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

*JavaScript*

```
var str = "s._2234.name.8923482.jpg";
var arr = str.split('.');
alert(arr[arr.length-2]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kYCAN/)

EDIT: As per comment `This doesn't work for s.sdf&#$.s.d__.name.s23444.tiff`

Updated Code

```
var str = "s.sdf&#$.s.d__.name.s23444.tiff";
var arr = str.split('.');
var desiredStr = arr[arr.length - 2].match(/\d+/)
alert(desiredStr);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4UPr/)

Comment: This doesn't work for `s.sdf&#$.s.d__.name.s23444.tiff`, as the `s` is still there.

Comment: @TomFenech, Hope http://jsfiddle.net/W4UPr/ fulfills requirement

Answer (score 1):

Use `\d+\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:$|\s)`  To explain this, it looks for the digits `[0-9]` (that's what `\d` does) one or more times (that's what `+` does) as long as it's followed by a `.` and letters followed by the end of the string.

Comment: What about `new_york.0001.tga`?

Comment: You can put as many extensions as you want inside the `()` separated by the `OR` operator, `|`.  So, replace `(.jpg|.tiff)` with `(.jpg|.tiff|.tga)` etc.

Comment: I believe a generic solution would be cleaner and safer.

Comment: Unfortunately, cases like `2234.name` (given in `s._2234.name.8923482.jpg`) make it difficult to allow any sort of made-up extension after a `.`.

Comment: The thing about extensions is that they usually come at the end of the file name... You should try to play on that! Who said `123.name` shouldn't be a valid file?

Comment: Editing now, I think I've got it.

Comment: Careful, this matches `123` in `123.abc1.12.jpg` and doesn't match `123.abc` alone. What about replacing `[^.A-Za-z]` (which demands a character) with something like `(?:$|\s)`?

Comment: +1'd, and editing now.  I was looking for a more elegant solution, but I'm fairly new to regex's as well.

Comment: Well the `\s` is only useful if each line isn't only the filename... If it's the only only thing, we can use something like `\d+\.[^.]+$` to catch the good part, maybe `\d+(?=\.[^.]+$)` or `(\d+)\.[^.]+$` to select only the digits, and we're good to go. I don't know about the elegancy, but this feels clean to me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using JS the RegExp `/\d+\.\D+$/` would capture the numbers and the extension. `.split('.')[0]` would get the numbers alone.

Comment: This works if the data is correctly formatted, but it would match `123.name.jgp`... Why not use `[^.]` instead of `\D`?

Comment: Quote: `All image names padding number, will be directly before the extension, that's the only thing that's continuous in the filename.`

Comment: I saw that; it just seemed a best practice to me to match, indeed, the "number directly before the extension", instead of matching "the last number in the name file" and rely on the data being well formatted.

Comment: I don't think any RegExp can account for `foo.bar6782.2389791.23879.file` and `foor.bar.1.2.3.34.54.file` if the extensions are `.23879.file` and `.3.34.54.file` respectively, unless the padding number has some sort of defining algorithm.

Comment: Sure, if there's no distinction between the extension and file number... But your expression doesn't account for these either. And `\d+\.[^.]+$` would match something like `102.ddl3`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [`array_pop`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

```
<?php
$str='s._2234.name.8923482.jpg';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $str, $matches);
echo array_pop($matches[0]); //"prints" 8923482
```

The above regular expression matches all the numbers and then prints the last matched number using the `array_pop()`

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/137759)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the filenames are always in the format `filename.padding.extension`, you can work with that:

```
$files = array("new_york.0001.tga", // Should find 0001
"s._2234.name.8923482.jpg", // Should find 8923482
"s.sdf&#$.s.d__.name.s23444.tiff"); // Should find 23444

foreach ($files as $f) {
    $parts = explode('.', $f);  
    preg_match("/\d+/", $parts[count($parts)-2], $padding);
    echo $padding[0];
}
```

`explode` splits each filename into parts, separated by the `.`. You want the second-to-last element of the `explode`d array. `preg_match` is used to pick out the numeric part.

#### output

```
0001
8923482
23444
```

Alternatively, you could use [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
foreach ($files as $f) {
    $split = preg_split("/\.[^\d]*/", $f);
    echo $split[count($split)-2];       
}
```